# NSUserDefault Registered defaults initial display in NSMenuItem bindings

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, cocoa-bindings

What is the order of operations you need to execute in order for NSMenuItem(s) that are bound to NSUserDefault keys to display the registered default values?

I am registering the default values, but my NSMenuItems are not showing up with the default's that I registered when I launch my app.

Comment: Thank you for *not* having tagged this question with Xcode! +1 just for that.

Comment: I've been using SO for 5 months, but never joined until recently, so I kinda know whats up.

Comment: then you probably know how nitpicky I am about beginners confusing Xcode with the compiler with Objective-C with Cocoa etc... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent most of the morning chasing this down, and most of the answers out there seem to be fragmentary, so thought I would share.

1) Bind your menu items to:

- Shared User Defaults
- Controller Key:values
- Model Key Path:keyName (in this case Deduplication_Target)

2) Register your defaults before awakeFromNib gets called, I did it in the + (void)initialize method in my AppDelegate.  (applicationDidFinishLaunching, (id)init, applicationWillFinishLaunching, none of these worked)

```
+ (void)initialize {
    [self setupDefaults];
}
```

3) Initialize your defaults dictionary with NSNumbers for BOOL values, despite examples out there that show them initialized as NSStrings:

```
NSString *const KEY_DEDUPLICATION_TARGET = @"Deduplication_Target";
NSString *const KEY_DEDUPLICATION_SOURCE = @"Deduplication_Source";
+ (void)setupDefaults {    
    NSDictionary* userDefaultsValuesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], KEY_DEDUPLICATION_TARGET, 
                                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], KEY_DEDUPLICATION_SOURCE, 
                                            nil];

    // set them in the standard user defaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userDefaultsValuesDict];
}
```

That solved it for me.

For reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/NSUserDefaultsController.html